# Few actions in else (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Is it proper to use multiple statements in one of the conditional clauses of a ternary boolean operator? For example:

```
$('#loadMore').click(function () {
    x= (x+5 <= size_div) ? x+4 : size_div & $('#loadMore').hide();
    $('#postList div:lt('+x+')').show();
});
```

In the else condition, I want to assign `size_div` to `x` and run the statement `('#loadMore').hide()`.

Is this the right way to do this, or is there a better way?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: You should better try in the more usual form, like `if` `else`

Comment: sure,  now I see it's a better solution thank you

Comment: If for some reason you wish to keep using the ternary operator, you could do like this: x = (x +5 <= size_div) ? (x+4) : ($('#loadMore').hide(), size_div); This should either set x to x+4 or hide the specified element and set x to size_div. This works because the value assigned to x is the result of the last comma-separated operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would refactor this to be:

```
$('#loadMore').click(function () {
    if (x + 5 <= size_div) {
        x += 4; 
    } else {
        x = size_div; 
        $('#loadMore').hide();
    }

    $('#postList div:lt('+x+')').show();
});
```

I believe this is what you intend, and has the benefit of being <s>100%</s> 500% more readable.

Comment: good, I also tried variant like this, so I'll stop on it, thank you